# Using an IF statement with NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to use an `if` statement to recognize whether or not an entry has been saved to my core data file. In this instance, I would like to display the user's name in a text field so they can edit it and then re-save. Instead, it just takes every entry as a new even though it has been created. Also, if I try to display the text of the saved object, even in the `viewDidLoad` method, nothing displays.

Help would be appreciated, Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)savePressed:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if(playerObject) {

        //update exsisting
        [playerObject setValue:txtFieldName.text forKey:@"name"];


    }
    else {
        //create new player

        NSManagedObject *newPlayer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newPlayer setValue:txtFieldName.text forKey:@"name"];

    }


    //save
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Save Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Where do you set `playerObject`?

Comment: Check in viewDidLoad , if you are having an object in playerObject reference.

Answer (score 0):

Think you forgot to assign the newly created player to the iVar playerObject:

```objectivec
NSManagedObject *newPlayer = nil;

if(playerObject) {
    //update exsisting
    [playerObject setValue:txtFieldName.text forKey:@"name"];
} else {
    //create new player

    newPlayer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPlayer setValue:txtFieldName.text forKey:@"name"];

}

if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Save Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    if (newPlayer) {
        playerObject = newPlayer;
    }
}
```